# Import module in python3

Tags: python

I put hello.py in the Users/apple/Documents，when I try to import this module in IDLE, there is a SyntaxError in output.

**hello.py(everything in file):**

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

print('helloworld')
```

**Commands I try to run in the Python interpreter**

```
import sys
sys.path
['', '/Users/apple/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

import hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
import hello
File "/Users/apple/Documents/hello.py", line 1
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I follow the book to do in the terminal：

```
appletekiMacBook-Pro:~ apple$ python hello.py

python: can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

appletekiMacBook-Pro:~ apple$ chmod a+x hello.py
chmod: hello.py: No such file or directory


appletekiMacBook-Pro:~ apple$ ./hello.py
-bash: ./hello.py: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please **explicitly** state what the exact contents of `hello.py` are, what commands you are running in the Python interpreter, and what is output. For example, if you run the command `print("foo")` from the interpreter (or IDLE), then prefix it with `>>>`.

Comment: Your question confuses people. You put everything including input&output there and says it's `hello.py`, which I think is not in your real `hello.py`.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the contents of hello.py (open it in TextEdit and copy everything in the file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hello.py` file contains invalid Python syntax. The error message

```
File "/Users/apple/Documents/hello.py", line 1
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is indicating that the first line of the file contains the text `Python 3.4.3 (v3...etc)` which is not valid Python syntax. Edit your hello.py file so it looks like this: (Adding `#` to the front of the first few lines)

```
# Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

# WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable. Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

print('helloworld')
```

The reason you are getting 'No such file or directory' when you try to run it from Terminal is because you are not actually looking for it in the correct place.

`appletekiMacBook-Pro:~ apple$` in the prompt means your current working directory is your home directory (/Users/apple/), but from the error message, hello.py is in the Documents/ subdirectory. If you change your command to

```
appletekiMacBook-Pro:~ apple$ python Documents/hello.py
```

then it will run, once the first few lines are commented out.

Comment: Thx, I have found the right path, but there's still a syntaxerror.

Comment: hello.py: print('helloworld')

Comment: I have pasted everything in hello.py.

Comment: Edited the answer to show what's causing the Syntax error. The first 2 lines are comments, not python instructions, and so they need a comment sign at the start of the line (`#`) to tell the interpreter to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

The second question is easy, you're looking in the wrong directory.

You said:

> I put hello.py in the Users/apple/Documents

Then you:

```
appletekiMacBook-Pro:~ apple$ python hello.py
```

`~` is your home directory, and your `hello.py` lies in `/Users/apple/Documents`. You should execute `cd Documents` then run the above command.